# Chart.js — how to scale on width only

Tags: chart.js

I have a  Chart.js  v.1.1 How I can scale on  width only  for example:
top graphics http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB055J451

```
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/jsanz/uLUAT/
```

When i will try scale page, my chart to scale on the width and height, but  I want only width

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is it you want to do exactly?